# Request/Idea: Next to the main questions column, have a random column from other SO sites with questions

Tags: feature-request

I mainly use StackOverflow.com.
Sometimes I need to ask a question which isn't very programming-related yet I'm sure that if I'd ask this question in StackOverflow.com I'd get answers, good community.

When writing this very question I have the "main" block of the page (on the left) and on the right I see the "How to Format" div (or call it a column).

So, the idea is very simple;
Have the same column on the main page (of stackoverflow.com and "friends"), just that it takes **random questions from random sites under the SO family** and writes them in smaller yet with the same stats as normal so it'll be interesting to watch once in a while, you know, maybe something new....
 1) It'll give much **wider diversity of content** and I'm sure many will like it.
 2) To questioners it'll give the opportunity to have the **question exposed to many people of other trades** which might result in an even more interesting replies/answers.

*If you like the idea "stack overflow internet services, inc" I'm willing to sell it to you for ONLY 10,000 Reputation points (at StackOverflow.com eh?!) =)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up and marvel at the awesomeness that is the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™.

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks! Now, this requires a click - I vote to make it hard-shown on the page, because it's not like you're going to click this every time you visit your fav. site.